# Is there a way to extract a protobuf oneof int value?

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

**TL;DR:** In Go, is there any way to get the integer value of a protobuf oneof case?

Detail:

In C# I can easily query the integer value of a Oneof case using something like the following:

```
opcode = (int)ChannelMessage.ChannelActionOneofCase.Register; // opcode will equal 1
```

However in Golang, there does not appear to be anything that I can use to easily extract that integer value.

I know that I can switch on the type itself:

```
switch m.ChannelAction.(type) {
    
    case *proto.ChannelMessage_Register:
    ...
```

however in my case this will require me to unmarshal every message, which for certain types isn't strictly necessary since I'm required to send the opcode along every time.

If it's helpful, my ChannelMessage type looks like the following:

```
message ChannelMessage
{
    oneof ChannelAction
    {
        ChannelRegister register = 1;
        ChannelUnregister unregister = 2;
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *probably* not what you want to actually do, but the [google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect) package does have the necessary functions, if you need to refer to the [field numbers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#assigning_field_numbers) of the fields that are part of your `oneof`.

For example, assuming you've imported your protos as `pb`, to get the number 1 by name (as in your C# example) you can do:

```golang
desc := (&pb.ChannelMessage{}).ProtoReflect().Descriptor()
opcode := desc.Fields().ByName("register").Number()
```

(This isn't strictly specific to the `oneof`, since `oneof` fields are really just regular message fields with an additional constraint that only one of them may be set.)

Or to figure out which field number a `oneof` field is set to in message `m` without writing out a type switch, assuming you know one of them has definitely been set, you can do:

```golang
ref := m.ProtoReflect()
desc := ref.Descriptor()
num := ref.WhichOneof(desc.Oneofs().ByName("ChannelAction")).Number()
```

In both cases the result (`opcode`, `num`) will be a numeric type ([protoreflect.FieldNumber](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/reflect/protoreflect#FieldNumber) = [protowire.Number](https://pkg.go.dev/google.golang.org/protobuf/encoding/protowire#Number)) that has an underlying type of `int32` you can convert it to.

Comment: That's it!! I thought that maybe I could do it with the ProtoReflect() construct but never quite figured it out.  Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You are right, you can do that with type switch:

```
// my example used simple strings instead of custom messages.
example := proto.ChannelMessage{
    ChannelAction: &pbExample.ChannelMessage_Register{"foobar"},
}

t := example.GetChannelAction()
switch v := t.(type) {
case *pbExample.ChannelMessage_Register:
    fmt.Printf("register\n")
case *pbExample.ChannelMessage_Unregister:
    fmt.Printf("unregister\n")
default:
    fmt.Printf("I don't know about type %T!\n", v)
}

// what you also can do is to ask directly your oneOf case and try to typecast it.
val, ok := example.GetRegister().(int) // GetUnregister is other option.
if ok {
    // black magic happens here
}
```

Comment: Thank you, @Oleg!  I think this confirms what I suspected, which is that what I want to do doesn't quite exist for protobufs in golang.  It's not a huge deal, I'll just have to be a little bit more clever. :) Bottom example is close, but from what I understand is that you're just querying the instance of the message for its integer equivalent, but what I'd actually like to do is something similar directly on the types themselves (i.e. convert pbExample.ChannelMessage_Register to the corresponding integer val defined in the oneof statement, which I don't think Go supports the way that C# does).